# Cannot install miktex on Ubuntu 18

Tags: pdf, html, latex, pandoc

Ultimately the final goal is to convert HTML to PDF. I saw this solution:

https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf

but the above solution seems to require headless chrome in order to run. So instead of that, I am going to try to use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) which will in turn use [miktex](https://miktex.org/download) to generate TeX from HTML?

But when I install miktex, I get:

```
$  sudo apt-get install miktex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 miktex : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2) but it is not installable
          Depends: libhunspell-1.4-0 but it is not installable
          Depends: libicu57 (>= 57.1-1~) but it is not installable
          Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
          Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.3) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

does anyone know how to solve that dependency problem?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use texlive instead of miktex - even more so if you are on linux

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks, I took your advice, and this is what I got! https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/501

Comment: link on how to install texlive?

Comment: I always install texlive directly from the TUG website: https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html This will give a much more up-to-date version than what is usually distributed via the linux package managers

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the `universe` repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install miktex
```

Comment: Is that only for Ubuntu? I'm on Debian and I got the same error as OP, but then got `Error: 'universe' invalid` with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`